# Purpose of metadata.xml

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, component, custom-component

Can somebody explain what is the purpose of metadata.xml in components files? For example /components/com_content/metadata.xml

As it almost has no content and I've never seen this in use.

Comment: I just came across this post related to your question: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/7649

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the purpose of **metadata.xml** is storing the data that need to be shared across layouts:

each *layout*.xml inside of your view tmpl directory **extends metadata.xml**.

---

### So if you need to put **some request fields in each layout** - you can **simply add this fields to metadata.xml** and all the **layouts will inherit them**.

For example file `/site/view/examples/metadata.xml` can look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <view>
        <options var="additional_request_var">
            <default name="COM_EXAMPLE" msg="COM_EXAMPLE_DESC"/>
            <option name="COM_EXAMPLE_EXT" msg="COM_EXAMPLE_EXT_DESC" value="additional_request_var_value" />
        </options>
    </view>
</metadata>
```

More at https://github.com/joomplace/JooYii

Comment: Can you please share an example of metadata.xml and a layout xml where layout XML extends metadata.xml ? I did a dozen of tries and metadata.xml seem to be ignored. I need a correct metadata.xml structure. Thank you!

Comment: Done.  contact me if you have some questions.